# MKR1000 - Connecting to Pubnub

Tags: mkr1000

I don't know if it's a stupid question but I need some help.
I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-08-10-getting-to-know-arduinos-mkr1000/) and I want to connect my arduino to PubNub. In the tutorial it says that I have to 'open PubNub.h and switch the comments for the Ethernet and WiFi lines' with some code provided there. But, when I open the file PubNub.h the only thing in there is this:

```
/* -*- c-file-style:"stroustrup"; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*- */
#include "PubNubDefs.h"

class PubNub PubNub;
```

I'm quite new to this so I don't know much. I hope someone can help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the tutorial is now outdated and the PubNum library does not need the changes described in the tutorial.

The [PubNub library](https://github.com/pubnub/arduino) has an example titled [PubNubWifi101](https://github.com/pubnub/arduino/blob/master/examples/PubNubWifi101/PubNubWifi101.ino) which shows the client type being set with a `#define` before including the PubNub headers:

```
#include <WiFi101.h>
#define PubNub_BASE_CLIENT WiFiClient
#include <PubNub.h>
```

I don't have a MKR1000 to test with, but I was able to compile the example from the [tutorial](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pubnub/arduino-mkr1000/master/Simple_Publish.ino) by adding that single `#define` after the `#include <WiFi101.h>`.